# many to many filter in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, postman

I had an issue about filtering retrieving data in relation many to many

models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, unique=True, max_length=100)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='players')
```

seializers.py

```
class MyTeamListSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['name']
```

views.py

```
class MyTeamListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Team.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyTeamListSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    pagination_class = ProfileLimitPagination
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('players')
    filter_class = TeamFilter
```

filters.py

```
class TeamFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    teams = django_filters.CharFilter(
        players='players__id',
        lookup_type='contains',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('players', 'teams',)
```

now, what im trying to do is, retrieve list of my teams that im player in.

so i want to request my teams get response list of my teams.

i dont know what the problem exact but im new in django rest framework.

so, please any one have the solution please help me in my case or if you have another solution to do what i want.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get list of teams of specific player use `exact` lookup instead of `contains`:

```
class TeamFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    teams = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name='players_id',
        lookup_type='exact',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('players', 'teams',)
```

Also use `field_name` as argument instead of `players`.

If you want to show only current user's team, you'd better overrride view's `get_queryset` method:

```
class MyTeamListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyTeamListSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    pagination_class = ProfileLimitPagination
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('players')
    filter_class = TeamFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Team.objects.filter(players=self.request.user)
```

Comment: thank you for quick response, but im asking my self if i want get teams for specific player (requested by) i need just the team that related for the requested user,
in other language just my teams.
first question your code serve this point ?
second one how to get requset.user in filter ?
many thanks

Comment: @hishamDigital in this case you'd better override `get_queryset` method of your view. Check updated answer.

Comment: many thanks @neverwalkaloner updated answer worked fine with me.
really thanks
btw        
`return Team.objects.filter(players_exact=self.request.user)`
i removed `exact` from `players_exact` to work without any error
again thank you